# SharePoint Online Apps 64bit

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am writing a SharePoint 2013 Online Autohosted app. Everything works fine, but there is one problem I have. I Would like to use Controls like the DateTimeControl, which is in the Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls assembly. I included a reference to the dll and registered it in my .aspx page.

But when I try to use the controls in the lib, I get an exception, that it only runs on 64bit platforms. 
So I switched the configuration to 64bit and deployed the app. But now I am getting a bad image exception. Are the apps limited to 32bit?

best regards
Alex

Comment: All SharePoint Assemblies are 64bit, always have been since SharePoint 2010 - make sure you're built to AnyCPU.

Comment: It is set to Any CPU by default. I get the "...SharePoint library only 64bit mode..." exception when I try to run the app with Any CPU. Switching to 64 bit produces the BAD Image exception...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got no answers but I am pretty sure now, that there is no possibility to use the this SharePoint library for fancy controls.

There are Client side people chooser for example and a lot of extenstions to standard asp controls so I just reproduced the DateTimeControl and it looks now the same and works perfectly.

best regards
Alex

Comment: After some further research I now have clearance: At the moment it is not possible to use that library. Another drawback is that the Clien Side People Picker is only available on SharePoint hosted apps. I use a jquery autocomplete textbox now and it works fine.